# How to convert integer to string, preserving leading zeroes in C++ ? (Using to_string)

Tags: c++, type-conversion

When I am trying to convert the given integer to string through **to_string** function, It simply omits the leading zeroes of the integer.

Why ? & how to overcome this?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int n;
cin >> n;

string s = to_string(n);

cout << s;
}
```

Comment: Keep it as a string. Integers don't have "leading zeroes" (or have infinitely many perhaps).

Comment: But i have to take that zeroes in my string. then what should i do?

Comment: Read it into a `std::string` variable instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers doesn't have leading zeroes.

If you want a specific number of digits for the number, with leading zeros, you need to use I/O manipulators like [`set::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill):

```
std::cout << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << n << '\n';
```

That will print (at least) eight digits, with leading zeros if the value of `n` is not eight digits.

---

If you want to *store* a "number" with leading zeros in your program, for example a phone number or similar, then you need another data-type than plain integers (which as mentioned doesn't have leading zeros).

Most common is as a string (`std::string`).

Comment: Realize that if it is 8 or more digits long, there will NOT be any leading 0's, so you may consider outputting a '0' first, then setw(7)/setfill ...

Answer (score 0):

In C++20, you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) when it is supported by your compiler. So as for now, there isn't a convenient way to transform a number in a string with formatted output.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69810294/104774) already showed the solution with iostreams which I normally prefer, but for formatting, I think it's too verbose and some manipulators are remembered by the iostream while others aren't, so in this case, I advise to use the C-style [`std::snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) (maybe a bit controversial in C++). The formatting also needs some learning but is more concise. The string is written in a char array that the caller has to provide and the result has then to be copied to a string.

```
int inp = 28;
char result[10];
int len = std::snprintf(result, 9, "%08d", inp);
std::string str_res(result, len);
```